# Find all div's beginning with id="string", iterate through result and change their id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which creates div's with numbered id's (div0, div1, div2). Each div contains a button to delete the div. The buttons are also numberes (delete_div0, delete_div1, delete_div2).

After delete e.g. div0, I want to reorganize everything so it starts from 0 again (in this case div1 -> div0 and div2 -> div1.

Another example: Delete div1, div0 -> div0, div2 -> div1.

Any help?

```js
var counter_div = 0;

$("#add_div").click(() => {
  $("#divs").append("<div id='div" + counter_div + "'>Div " + counter_div + " <button id='delete_div" + counter_div + "' type='button'>X</button></div>");

  //add listener
  $("#delete_div" + counter_div).click((event) => {
    nr = event.target.id.substring(
      event.target.id.length - 1,
      event.target.id.length
    );

    $("#div" + nr).remove();
  })

  // this is where I am struggling reorganizing divs
  function reorganize() {
    $("div[id^=div]").each((element) => {
      $(this).prop("id", "div" + element);
    });

  }
  reorganize();

  counter_div++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='add_div' type='button'>Add div</button></div>

<div id='divs'></div>
```

EDIT:
Thanks to everbody, I found a mix out of every solution.

```
$("#delete_div" + counter_div).click((event) => {
    //remove div
    $(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();

    //reorder all ingredients
    $("div[id^=div]").each((element) => {
        $(this)
        .find("div[id^='div']")
        .eq(element)
        .prop("id", "div" + element);
    };
});
```

Probalby not the most beautiful solution, but it works. What I did not understand yet is why $(this) in the each-function gives different results depending on which syntax I use.

```
$("div[id^=div]").each(function(element) {console.log($(this))};
```

is different to

```
$("div[id^=div]").each((element) => {console.log($(this))};
```

Comment: can we see the html aswell, it is impossible to know what "deleting one of the div's" does for example

Comment: Create [mre] using SO snippet by pressing `<>` button in editor.

Comment: I have to admit, my question was quite sloppy. Sorry for that. I hope it's better now.

Comment: Why do you want to change `id`? I guess you might want to update text instead. e.g. If I remove `Div 1` then text in `Div 2` should set to `Div 1`,  `Div 3` should set to `Div 2` etc.

Comment: Actually this is all happening with input tags and later I am reading from the tag's id sequentially. So I would like to change the id's. Not a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#delete_div" + counter_div).click((event) => {
    //remove div
    $(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();

    //reorder all ingredients
    $("div[id^=div]").each((element) => {
        $(this)
        .find("div[id^='div']")
        .eq(element)
        .prop("id", "div" + element);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform delete with `$(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();`.

Similarly if you want to select any `input` from on such button click you can use `$(event.currentTarget).parent().find("input")`.

Or you want to loop over `divs` and find all inputs then you can use :

```
$('#divs > div[id^=div]').each(function(k) {
    var allInputs = $(this).find('input');
});
```

```js
var counter_div = 0;

$("#add_div").click(() => {
  $("#divs").append("<div id='div" + counter_div + "'>Div " + counter_div + " <button id='delete_div" + counter_div + "' type='button'>X</button></div>");

  //add listener
  $("#delete_div" + counter_div).click((event) => {  
    $(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();
  })

  counter_div++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='add_div' type='button'>Add div</button></div>

<div id='divs'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First call your reorganize on remove

```
    $("#div" + nr).remove();
      reorganize();
  })
```

then:

```
   var numDivsNum=-1;
//set first id -1
  function reorganize() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll("#divs > div[id^='div']")].forEach(el => {      
      el.id="div"+(++numDivsNum);
// for each element add new id +1
      el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML + "New id= " +numDivsNum;
    });

  }
```

And your selector was wrong, it should be:

```
div[id^='div']
```

not

```
div[id^=div]
```

```js
var counter_div = 0;

$("#add_div").click(() => {
  $("#divs").append("<div id='div" + counter_div + "'>Div " + counter_div + " <button id='delete_div" + counter_div + "' type='button'>X</button></div>");

  //add listener
  $("#delete_div" + counter_div).click((event) => {
    nr = event.target.id.substring(
      event.target.id.length - 1,
      event.target.id.length
    );

    $("#div" + nr).remove();
      reorganize();
  })

  // this is where I am struggling reorganizing divs
   var numDivsNum=-1;
  function reorganize() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll("#divs > div[id^='div']")].forEach(el => {      
      el.id="div"+(++numDivsNum);
      el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML + "New id is id='div" +numDivsNum+"'";
    });

  }


  counter_div++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='add_div' type='button'>Add div</button></div>

<div id='divs'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-index them like this:

```
$('div[id^="div"]').each(function(k) {
    $(this).prop('id', 'div' + k);
});
```

But personally I'd give them all a class so you don't have to rely on the *begins with `div`* selector, and then consider using `data-id` instead of id.  `data-id` will be easier to extract as an integer later and that appears to be your goal. Maybe something like this?

```
$('div.my_class').each(function(k) {
    $(this).data('id', k);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have almost done
But there are some stuff that needs to be fixed

```
$(this).parent('div').eq(0).remove();
```